# Sample Space for Bernoulli Trials & Independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An example of how measure theory has obfuscated something once simple to me.

Consider tossing a coin and observing the face-up side, either $H$ or $T$.  The sample space is clearly $\Omega = \{H,T\}$ and the sigma algebra is $\mathcal{F} = 2^\Omega$.  We'll also have a probability measure such that $P(H) = p$.

Now consider tossing the coin twice and again observing the face-up side.  Now the sample space for this experiment is $\Omega^\prime = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ and the sigma algebra is $\mathcal{F}^\prime = 2^{\Omega^\prime}$.  Again, we have some probability measure $P^\prime$ on this measurable space $(\Omega^\prime, \mathcal{F}^\prime)$.

The two tosses are clearly independent, and so it should be that, e.g., $P^\prime(HT) = p(1-p)$.  But, it seems this doesn't have to be the case for two reasons:

1. How would we actually obtain the equality $P^\prime(HT) = p(1-p)$?  Usually, we might say $P(H \cap T) = P(H) \cdot P(T) = p(1-p)$ for independent events $H$ and $T$.  But, the set $H \cap T = \emptyset$ in $\mathcal{F}$, so this we should get $P(H \cap T) = 0$.  Furthermore, how would we get to measuring with $P$ from $P^\prime$?
2. The set $\{H\} \notin \mathcal{F}^\prime$, so how does $P^\prime(H)$ even make sense?

I've really confused myself, and would appreciate some extra eyes on this.

Answer (score 3):

In $\Omega'$, the event $\{H\}$ (or entity $H$ alone) is ambiguous, because we don't know if you're referring to the first toss or the second toss. To be clear you need to use notation like $H_1$ to denote the event that the *first* toss is heads. Then for sure $H_1 = \{HH, HT\}$ is in your sigma algebra. Similarly $T_2 := \{HT, TT\}$ is in your sigma algebra, and $H_1$ and $T_2$ are independent, since $$P'(H_1 \cap T_2)=P'(\{HT\})=p(1-p)=P'(H_1)P'(T_2).$$
IMO the measure theory hasn't obfuscated this; rather, it's making us aware that sometimes our notation can be sloppy and needs more precision.

Comment: @grant_chat Okay, so instead of defining $P(H) = p$ as in my question, it is more clear to define $P^\prime(H_1) = p$, correct?

Comment: @grant_chat But then, what about the probability of an $H$ on the second toss?  Why would this necessarily be the same as an $H$ on the first toss, and hence, it seems there is still ambiguity in defining the "probability of an $H$.?  I.e., if $H_2 = \{HH, TH\}$, why would I expect $P(H_1) = P(H_2)$?

Comment: @bcf  Right, there is no reason to expect $P(H_1)=P(H_2)$. Instead of defining the individual probs of each possible sequence of heads and tails, the typical way to ensure independence is to use a *product space* of ordered tuples from a basic Bernoulli probability space, i.e. $\Omega' := \Omega \times\Omega$, $\mathcal F':=\mathcal F\times\mathcal F$, and $P'$ is the product measure, which forces independence. In the product space the measures being 'multiplied' don't have to be the same: you can have a Bernoulli($p_1$) for the first toss and a Bernoulli($p_2$) for the second toss, and so on.